# JSON.parse string invalid character issue

Tags: javascript, c#, json, razor, model-view-controller

I am not able to figure out what is the problem with JSON in the following code.

This is working fine:

```
var a = JSON.parse('[{"label":"not applicable"},{"label":"see items"},{"label":"40 days"},{"label":"suntest"}]');
```

But this throws an exception, "Invalid Character" :

```
var b = JSON.parse('[{"label":"234"},{"label":"Sunny AG, Sunny Me- Be Cars, Ben., Bu 60, DE 71059, Sind, Discharge p no. 9711\r\n"},{"label":"C207346"}]');
```

While debugging I copied above runtime code. Actual code is in C# MVC as:

```
var a= JSON.parse('@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.ShipToAddressCodeList))');
```

Comment: Keep in mind, apostrophe in C# are char, not strings.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to escape the `\r\n`. JavaScript interprets the `\`'s in `\r\n` as escape characters, but really they are part of the string and should stay. Adding another `\` in front of each `\` fixes it, by escaping the escape character so the JSON parser treats it literally:

```
var b = JSON.parse('[{"label":"234"},{"label":"Sunny AG, Sunny Me- Be Cars, Ben., Bu 60, DE 71059, Sind, Discharge p no. 9711\\r\\n"},{"label":"C207346"}]');
```

Comment: Thanks @Joe for quick reply and help....you have also removed Hyphen(-) from the string between "Me Be". Should I need to remove that also?

Comment: C# gives the non-literal interpretation to "\n" here, not JavaScript. You can tell because there's *no JavaScript here* and yet you still have the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape your `\r\n` as `\\r\\n`

```
var b = JSON.parse('[{"label":"234"},{"label":"Sunny AG, Sunny Me- Be Cars, Ben., Bu 60, DE 71059, Sind, Discharge p no. 9711\\r\\n"},{"label":"C207346"}]');
```